# Why is my state in React defined in one function but undefined in another?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scope

I'm making a phone app using React Native and I have this component:

```
export default class MemberPage extends Component {

constructor(props){
super(props);
var m = this.props.navigation.getParam("member", {member:{party:"R"}});
this.state = {
    member: m
};
if(this.state.member.party === "R") {

    this.state.bgColor = "#7f0000";
}else {
    this.state.bgColor = "#303F9F";
}
//this.renderContent.bind(this);
}

renderNavBar() {
return(
    <View style={styles.navContainer}>
    <View style={styles.statusBar} />
        <View style={styles.navBar}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.iconLeft} onPress={() => {}}>
            <Icon name="add" size={25} color="#fff" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.iconRight} onPress={() => {}}>
                <Icon name="search" size={25} color="#fff" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                        </View>
);
}

renderContent() {

console.log("rendering Content")
console.log(this.state);

return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <SocialAccounts/>
        <ContactInfo phone={this.state.member.phone} email={this.state.member.email} office_loc={this.state.member.office} />
        <GoverningRecord />
            <PersonalInfo />
            </View>
);
}

// backgroundImage={images.background}


getFullMemberName(member){
var f = member.first_name;
var m = (member.middle_name ? member.middle_name : "");
var l = member.last_name;
var s = (member.suffix ? member.suffix : "");
return[f,m,l,s].filter(a => a !== "").join(" ");
}

render(){
// const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
console.log(this.state.member);
return(
    <ReactNativeParallaxHeader

    headerMaxHeight={250}
    extraScrollHeight={20}
    backgroundColor={this.state.bgColor}
    title={this.getFullMemberName(this.state.member)}
    backgroundImageScale={1.2}
    titleStyle={styles.titleStyle}
    containerStyle={styles.container}
    contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
    innerContainerStyle={styles.container}
    headerMinHeight={HEADER_HEIGHT}
    renderContent={this.renderContent}

    scrollViewProps={{
        onScrollBeginDrag: () => console.log('onScrollBeginDrag'),
        onScrollEndDrag: () => console.log('onScrollEndDrag'),
    }}
    />
);
}
```

}

And when I run it I get this output.

```
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 64ms.
Running application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
Object {
  "api_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/B001261.json",
  "contact_form": "https://www.barrasso.senate.gov/public/index.cfm/contact-form",
  "cook_pvi": null,
  "crp_id": "N00006236",
  "cspan_id": "1024777",
  "date_of_birth": "1952-07-21",
  "dw_nominate": 0.538,
  "facebook_account": "johnbarrasso",
  "fax": null,
  "fec_candidate_id": "S6WY00068",
  "first_name": "John",
  "gender": "M",
  "google_entity_id": "/m/02rsm32",
  "govtrack_id": "412251",
  "icpsr_id": "40707",
  "id": "B001261",
  "ideal_point": null,
  "in_office": true,
  "last_name": "Barrasso",
  "last_updated": "2019-12-03 19:50:32 -0500",
  "leadership_role": "Senate Republican Conference Chair",
  "lis_id": "S317",
  "middle_name": null,
  "missed_votes": 0,
  "missed_votes_pct": 0,
  "next_election": "2024",
  "ocd_id": "ocd-division/country:us/state:wy",
  "office": "307 Dirksen Senate Office Building",
  "party": "R",
  "phone": "202-224-6441",
  "rss_url": "https://www.barrasso.senate.gov/public/?a=rss.feed",
  "senate_class": "1",
  "seniority": "13",
  "short_title": "Sen.",
  "state": "WY",
  "state_rank": "junior",
  "suffix": null,
  "title": "Senator, 1st Class",
  "total_present": 0,
  "total_votes": 374,
  "twitter_account": "SenJohnBarrasso",
  "url": "https://www.barrasso.senate.gov",
  "votes_against_party_pct": 3.23,
  "votes_with_party_pct": 96.77,
  "votesmart_id": "52662",
  "youtube_account": "barrassowyo",
}
rendering Content
undefined
rendering Content
undefined

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.member')
* components/MemberPage.js:99:6 in renderContent
- node_modules/react-native-parallax-header/index.js:335:8 in RNParallax#renderScrollView
- node_modules/react-native-parallax-header/index.js:346:8 in RNParallax#render
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13042:21 in finishClassComponent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12970:4 in updateClassComponent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:307:15 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:531:36 in invokeGuardedCallback
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20488:8 in beginWork$$1
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19370:24 in performUnitOfWork
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19347:39 in workLoopSync
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18997:22 in renderRoot
* [native code]:null in renderRoot
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18709:28 in runRootCallback
* [native code]:null in runRootCallback
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5642:32 in runWithPriority$argument_1
- node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:643:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5638:22 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5627:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18796:28 in batchedUpdates$1
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2709:30 in batchedUpdates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2794:17 in batchedUpdates$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2870:28 in receiveTouches
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I can't seem to figure out why I am able to access `this.state.member` or just `this.state` from within `render()` but not from within `renderContent()` which is called from within `render().` I was reading about the bind function and thought maybe I needed to use that but that doesn't seem to make a difference for me.

Does anyone know why am I able to access my state from my render function but not from another function called from the render function in the same class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their are two types of functions, simple functions like

`renderContent(){ bodyhere }`

and fat arrow functions like

`const renderContent = () =>{ bodyhere }`

In simple function `renderContent()` your `this` keyword is reffering to its parent `renderContent` which doesn't contain any definition for `state` that's why it's saying undefined.

Solution: Change your simple function `renderContent()` to fat arrow function :

`const renderContent = () {}`

Another solution is to change

`renderContent={this.renderContent}`

to

`renderContent={()=>this.renderContent()}`

Answer (score 0):

i thought binding but you had said that. maybe you should try it again. probably, problem is binding. you can use arrow function notation. if it doesn't work, you should check reactnativeparallaxheader.

Comment: I went through the source and it just calls the function, doesn't do anything to it. Also same thing if I just call the function myself.